# will _paginate in show views

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, will-paginate

I have Categories view which list some items based on which categories the belong

now i want to paginate items on that category

So, in category  controllerI have

```
<code>
    def show
      @category = Category.find(params[:id])
    end
</code>
```

and in views/categories/show.html.erb

```
<code>
    <%= will_paginate %> 
    <ul>
    <% @category.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <li><%= link_to image_tag( photo.image_url(:thumb).to_s ), photo %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
    <%= will_paginate %>
</code>
```

How to paginate those

items ??
I cant understand the documentation [github will_paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate/blob/8888651be8d6656bdf2378731d91a8badbaa2556/README.rdoc) however i know that if its just I can easily replace Category.all with

`Category.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 20, :order => 'created_at DESC')`

please help??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
def show
  @category = Category.find(params[:id])
  @photos = @category.photos.order('created_at DESC')
                            .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 20)
end
```

and in your view, change:

```
<% @category.photos.each do |photo| %>
```

into:

```
<% @photos.each do |photo| %>
```